# Fusioncharts Javascript fallback has crowded X axis

Tags: javascript, label, fusioncharts

I am using the commercial version of FusionCharts (v3.2.1) and I have noticed that the Javascript fallback doesn't seem to respect the "labelStep" or "showLabel" properties. Additionally, the Flash version automatically hides labels when the axes are too crowded, while the Javascript fallback does not.

In other words, all X axis labels are showing at all times if the user doesn't have Flash installed. This gets pretty bad if the graph has more than a handful of values.

Is there a way to get around this bug, or am I stuck? If there is a way around, what might that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking forward to next release.

Got a sneak peek at http://www.fusioncharts.com/labs/3.2.2 .

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was beginning to suspect that this was the case, but it's nice to have confirmation.